# Как перезаписать объект при переборе async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

```
async.forEachOf(allFlights, function (flight, key, callback) {
    Airport.findOne({_id: flight.airportFrom}, function(err, airport) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        flight.airportFrom = airport; // Тут почему то не перезаписывает
        callback();
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(allFlights);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) не угодил? Можно же, например, так:

```
async.map(allFlights, function (flight, callback) {
    Airport.findOne({_id: flight.airportFrom}, function(err, airport) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        flight.airportFrom = airport;
        callback(null, flight);
    });
}, function (err, flights) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.json(flights);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так

```
function array_async_action(input,action,callback,resolve_all){
    var promises =[];
    for(var i in input){
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var key=this;
            action(input[key],function(err,res){
                if(err && !resolve_all){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    resolve(res||err);
                }
            });
        }.bind(i)))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(res){
        callback(null,res);
    }).catch(callback);
}

array_async_action(allFlights,function(flight,callback){
    Airport.findOne({_id: flight.airportFrom}, function(err, airport) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        flight.airportFrom = airport; // Тут почему то не перезаписывает
        callback(null,flight);
    });
},function(err,allFlights){
    //
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(allFlights);
});
```

Comment: Вы повторили `async.map` на Promise. Зачем?)

Comment: Потому что 1) не слыхал про async 2) Не люблю лишние зависимости. Считаю, что подтягивать целый модуль/библиотеку из за одной фичи, которую можно реализовать в 10 строк - удел дилетантов, которые не могут написать эти 10 строк 3) Вследствие 2 имею набор сниппетов, которые реализуют подобные фичи. Я мог бы сделать свою бибилотеку, но см. пункт 2

Comment: Вот когда вы каждый из своих "снипетов" покроете хотя бы половиной тестов, используемых в сторонних решениях, вот тогда и будете рассуждать про дилетантов. Да и подход с повторным использованием кода не просто так придумали и пропагандируют.

Comment: Вы кажется не в курсе, что (юнит)тесты пишутся вместе с кодом, и что  "тесты, используемые в сторонних решениях" покрывают только эти самые сторонние решения.

Comment: Эти тесты гарантируют, что сторонние решения работают. Так же как и комьюнити, использующее эти решения. А вот при использовании самописных велосипедов такой гарантии нет ;)

Comment: А что касается данного конкретного вопроса: ТС **уже** использует async. И игнорировать этот факт, по-просу глупо

Comment: И у него что-то не очень получается.

Comment: Это не повод врячивать собственный велосипед туда, где это не нужно

Comment: Холивар. Вы предпочитаете dependency hell, я предпочитаю контролируемый код. Нам лучше не общаться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32238/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-darth).

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/275159/